# WCF file upload from desktop application end to end tutorial?

Tags: wcf, file-upload

Does anyone know of an end to end tutorial/example showing how to upload binaries to a WCF host from say a desktop application (probably Silverlight or WPF but it most likely doesn't matter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking a look at Streaming example on [IDesign.net](http://idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=5&tabid=11). This is a site of company whose principal is Juval Löwy, who wrote a book [Programming WCF Services 3rd Edition (O'Reilly 2010)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526997). This site has a number of WCF examples based on various scenario (requires email to d/l). Streaming example may not be exactly file upload but it deals with handling large messages serialized over WCF...May be a good starting point.